# Convert 3D tensor to plotly volume format

Tags: python, numpy, plotly

I have a 3D density map represented by a 3D tensor
2 x 2 x 2 example:

```py
data = [
    [[v_1, v_2], [v_3,v_4]],
    [[v_5, v_6], [v_7,v_8]]
]
```

where v_n is the value at that point in space.

I want to represent this using a [Plotly 3D Volume Plot](https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/).
Plotly presents the following example:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-8:8:40j, -8:8:40j, -8:8:40j]
values = np.sin(X*Y*Z) / (X*Y*Z)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=values.flatten(),
    isomin=0.1,
    isomax=0.8,
    opacity=0.1, # needs to be small to see through all surfaces
    surface_count=17, # needs to be a large number for good volume rendering
))
```

I am at a bit of a loss on how to find `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `value`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I played around with  and looked up documentation for the flatten function and mgrid for a while but wasn't able to figure anything out.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71447386/how-is-the-plotly-3d-volume-plot-generated) question but that sadly didn't push me across the finish line either.